# FaceTime and iMessage - an error occurred during activation

Tags: macos, apple-id, error, facetime

I couldn't log in to FaceTime so I did a factory reset of my MacBook. It worked for a brief period of time and then suddenly it just logged out.

I believe it might have been after iCloud synced with keychain or after I changed my local host name and computer name.

I have seen other users facing this issue but no solutions. Is there a troubleshooting guide or should I just contact Apple support since I can't use their service without activation to my Mac?

Comment: I am not sure that this is a solution to your problem, but periodically, I would estimate once every two weeks, I notice that iMessage is signed out on one or both of my Macs, a MacBook Pro and a MacBook Mini. Every attempt at signing back in returns "An error occurred during activation". I will reboot either once or twice and iMessage will be signed in without me doing anything and I will get alerts on all Mac devices that my ID is being used on a new device. So the first thing I would do is try rebooting multiple times checking to see whether it signs in or not.

Answer (score 1):

Found [this apple support article covering this exact error:](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201422) - https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT201422

> **Check your device settings**
>
> 1. Make sure that you’re connected to a cellular data or Wi-Fi network. If you're using an iPhone, you need SMS
>      messaging to activate your phone number with iMessage and FaceTime.
>      Depending on your carrier, you might be charged for this SMS.
> 2. Go to Settings > General > Date & Time and make sure that your time zone is set correctly.
>
> ￼
>   **Turn off and restart iMessage and FaceTime**
>
> Go to Settings > Messages and turn off iMessage.
>
> Go to Settings > FaceTime and turn off FaceTime.
>
> Restart your device.
>
> Turn iMessage and FaceTime back on.
>
> ￼
>   **Still not activated after a day?** It might take up to 24 hours to activate iMessage and FaceTime. If the issue continues after 24 hours,
>   follow these steps:
>
> Make sure that your device has the latest version of iOS.
>
> If you're using an iPhone, contact your carrier to make sure that you
>   can receive SMS messages.
>
> Contact Apple Support.

It has the links to support once you've ruled out the easy things like a setting on your Mac. They can help if your network connection isn't reaching Apple's servers or if there's an issue with your account on the server side.

Comment: The problem is for macs, your link is for ios devices.

Answer (score 0):

If in the end you don’t know what the reason is, call Apple support. Perhaps your Apple ID is blocked due to random spam from your device.

Comment: Hi Oleg. Can you expand on what writing to Russia entails? The "they" and "them" isn't very clear or useful for others. I'm not going to -1 vote this since this is your first post here (Welcome to the site!) but without some reference if you're contacting Apple or a carrier or the Russian government - it's going to be hard for anyone to make use of your experience and knowledge to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have tried all the things you could find on the internet. This possible solution applies to a situation where you may have been able to sign in from your iphone but cannot do same on your mac. 
1. Go to Settings on your iphone
2. Proceed to facetime
3. Enable "use your apple ID for facetime"

This might be the solution you need